# Java Script File Reader class is not reading the contents properly

Tags: javascript, utf-8, filereader

I am using readAsText method in FileReader class (java script) with encoding type as "UTF-8" to read a file from client.  It works well for all kind of characters with ascii values ranging from 1 to 65000. The only problem I have is, when I read chunk by chunk from the file, any char has ascii value after 3000 sometimes not read properly, After the investigation, I found that it is happening only when I do this reading for big files and the particular char is accidently sitting as first letter of a chunk. And I tested with multiple chunks of a file. This problem is not happening for all the chunks, happening one or 2 chunks out of 10. This is weird and strange. Am I missing something here? and do we have any other options to read local file in Java script? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide code and sample data

Answer (score 0):

this might be one solution

```js
new Blob(['hi']).text().then(console.log)
```

Here is another, not so cross browser friendly... but this could work...

```js
new Blob(['foo']) // or new File(['foo'], 'test.txt')
  .stream()
  .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream('utf-8'))
  .pipeTo(new WritableStream({
    write(part) {
      console.log(part)
    }
  }))
```

Another lower level solution that don't depend on WritableStream or TextDecoderStream would be to use regular TextDecoder with stream option by doing

```
var res = ''
const decoder = new TextDecoder()
res += decoder.decode(chunk1, { stream: true })
res += decoder.decode(chunk2, { stream: true })
res += decoder.decode(chunk3, { stream: true })
res += decoder.decode() // flush the end
```

how u get each chunk could be by using `new Response(blob).body` or by `blob.stream()` or simply slicing the blob using `blob.slice(start, end)` and use `FileReader.prototype.readAsArrayBuffer()`